# soundcloud python: unathorized for url issue

Tags: python, api, soundcloud

Using the official python library we get this issue at after a few requests.

The same code works on one request and then breaks in the second request.

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token
```

This happens on our test account. We need this to work as we have an issue with our pro account which we need to replicate on our test account so we can safely work on this.

The error happens on the creation of the client instance - it does not make it to the "print" statement that follows. All the API keys and username/password details stay the same and are correct but continue to fail on some occasions and succeed on others.

```
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id=SC_CLIENT_ID,
                           client_secret=SC_CLIENT_SECRET,
                           username=SC_USERNAME,
                           password=SC_PASSWORD)

print (client.get('/me').username)
```

The system we have only uploads/manages data from our own account.

Comment: Do you have a legit and still working client id and secret? Because I doubt that. There is a work around to make it work even without official client secret.

Comment: Having the same issue as well. Soundcloud seems to rate-limit the password credentials grant after 10 requests in a short time.